# Desambiguar etiqueta [datetimepicker]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

He estado viendo que las preguntas de C# del componente DateTimePicker que al parecer pertenece a [winforms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) (Yo no lo he usado) se están mezclando con las preguntas de un componente que yo he visto para bootstrap muy famoso también conocido como [Date time picker](https://programacion.net/articulo/bootstrap_datetimepicker-_o_como_anadir_un_calendario_a_un_campo_input_1796).

Para desambiguarla se me ocurre dejar [datetimepicker](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetimepicker) para [c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) y para el componente compatible con bootstrap usar [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-datetimepicker) como lo he visto en SOen.

Ejemplos:

- [¿Cómo puedo definir el formato del valor que recibo de un datetimepicker en c#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371269/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-definir-el-formato-del-valor-que-recibo-de-un-datetimepicker-en-c)
- [configurar DateTimePicker con intervalos de 15 minutos en los valores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400097/datetimepicker-habilitar-los-minutos-cada-15-1000-1015-1030-1045-1100#)

¿Por qué no lo hago yo mismo?

Sinceramente no tengo la suficiente experiencia trabajando con ambos como para decirles si el datepicker petenece siempre a windows forms y C#, si el componente debe usarse siempre con bootstrap, si o por quien fue desarrollado, o si hay forma de hacer el renombrado de manera automatizada.

Al parecer hay otro datepicker similar para jQuery: [jquery-ui-datepicker](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-datepicker).

Comment: aunque comparto, es algo que no se si tiene solucion... deberiamos aplicarlo tambien para el componente de java? para algun otro componente en otro lenguaje? bootstrap tiene uno.. buenisimo.. tambien el input en html se puede transformar a un datetimepicker... para mi.. todo ese tema es confuso... y el componente deberia ser generico... dudo que alguien siga las preguntas por componentes...

Comment: De hecho hay dos para jQuery: [tag:jquery-datepicker] y [tag:jquery-ui-datepicker]. Y aquí ya tenemos [tag:bootstrap-timepicker] y [tag:timepicker-bootstrap], ambas con dos preguntas.

Comment: Esto es complicado si cogemos c# por ejemplo, hay el oficial de windows forms, librerías que lo contienen (ejemplo xceed), o se puede customizar el datepicker de wpf con pocos pasos para que actúe como el original y todos tienen sus pros y contras diferentes y su funcionamiento internamente es diferente.